# How to implement Session storage in Angular 4

Tags: angular, angular4-router, angular4-httpclient

Working in a e-Commerce Application ,for that I want to implement session storage ,I want to know about how to implement the session storage in Angular 4 and what are the step by steps to achieve this.

Please guide me to implement the session storage by using Angular 4.Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is not how Stackoverflow works: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: did you understand my question or not ...?

Answer (score 2):

Use sessionStorage to store the session :)

```
    let key: 'title'; 
    let value: 'session';
    sessionStorage.setItem(key, value);
```

and then retrieve your item like

```
const session = sessionStorage.getItem('key');
```

Note that this is only active until the user closes the browser. If you want your data to persist after the closing of the tab, use `localStorage` instead.